# Foreign key constraint fails when I want delete table

Tags: mysql, database, nette

When I am trying

```
drop tables users;
```

It shows error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `event_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
  `last_edit` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_id` (`users_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('admin','member','guest','registered') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'registered',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users_data` (
  `id` int(120) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_id` (`users_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_data_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `user_matches` (
  `user_id` int(120) NOT NULL,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_matches_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users_data` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_matches_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I think I did wrong foreign key but I am not sure how to change it correctly. Thank you for your any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't drop table: A foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100911/cant-drop-table-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit `drop table users` MySQL checks for referential integrity constraints violation when the deletion is about to be committed. This check fails because you have defined the following constraint of `events`:

`CONSTRAINT`events_ibfk_5`FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES`users`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

and at the same time on the `events` table the `users_id` field cannot be `NULL`. Therefore, upon dropping the table, the `users_id` is set to `NULL` which fails during commit. One possible way to work around this problem is to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on the `users_id` field on the `events` table.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to set users_id field to NULL, but still, I cannot drop users table.

Comment: Also i tried to run innodb status and it shows: LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2018-02-08 10:14:15 70000f1fb000  Cannot drop table `bp`.`users`
because it is referenced by `bp`.`events`

Comment: Can you try then deferring the constraints with the statement `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, then try the deletion of the table and then re-enable the foreign key checks with: `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`?