# pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'dob' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a datepicker for the date of in my forms, i decided to use he input type date which is supported by most some browsers. i keep getting this error anytime i try to create super user or migrate. I have removed my migrations for the app and added them back with `python manage.py makemigrations` but the problem still persists. i do not want to wipe out the database, i have tried this with postgres(local) and mysql(production) and the error is the same.

This is the traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'dob' cannot be null")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 157, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 800, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 179, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 179, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/navararl/repositories/health/aview/core/signals.py", line 10, in update_profile_signal
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/navararl/repositories/health/aview/core/models.py", line 38, in save
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 789, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 892, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 932, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1395, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 489, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/navararl/virtualenv/repositories/health/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'dob' cannot be null")
```

models.py

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   
    next_of_kin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=10, blank=True,null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    appointment_with = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='appontment_with', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD ='user'
    def save(self, *args, **kw):

        self.slug = slugify(f"{self.last_name}-{self.first_name}")
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kw)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_hospitals(self):
        return self.hospitals.all()
   
    @property
    def get_fullname(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.middle_name)
        return full_name.strip()
```

forms.py

```
class PatientForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Last Name')
    middle_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Middle Name')
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='address')
    next_of_kin = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Next of kin')
    dob = forms.DateField(help_text='Date of birth',
                          widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have to clean up the 'django_migrations' table.

this table tracks `migrate` history.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: in your database there would be a table named 'django_migrations'. find it and delete rows by app or name. @blockhead

Comment: i am now getting this error django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists") after i deleted all tables in the django_migrations and ran the migrate and makemigrations command again

Comment: to answer this, I need to know your migration status. universal solution 1. 
run some SQL queries to solve this state.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100911/cant-drop-table-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails/23293136#23293136  //2. backup your database and reset all migrations. before every try you should backup your database and ready to revert