# Error code 1217 in MySQL code

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the error: `Error 1217` in my `MySQL` code. My `MySQL` code is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Formed;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Band;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;

CREATE TABLE Formed(
    FormedID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    YearFormed int, 
    CountryFormed varchar(50), 
    CityFormed varchar(50), 
    BandMembers varchar(400), 
    PRIMARY KEY(FormedID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Track (
    TrackID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    AlbumID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Songs varchar (100), 
    TrackNumber varchar (20), 
    Title varchar (30), 
    TrackDuration varchar (4), 
    PRIMARY KEY (TrackID)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Album(
    AlbumID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TrackID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    BandID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    KEY(TrackID),
    KEY(BandID),
    Price varchar(5), 
    PublicationDate varchar(11), 
    Title varchar(30), 
    Genre varchar (36),
    PRIMARY KEY(AlbumID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Band(
    BandID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    AlbumID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    KEY(AlbumID),
    RecordLabel varchar(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY(BandID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    CName varchar (20), 
    CPhone int (11), 
    CEmail varchar (50), 
    CPPaid varchar (50), 
    CPDate date, 
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE Track 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album(AlbumID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Album
ADD FOREIGN KEY (TrackID) REFERENCES Track(TrackID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Album
ADD FOREIGN KEY (BandID) REFERENCES Band(BandID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Band
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album(AlbumID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And I'm getting the error `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album` `Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`, it also happens for the other `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` lines. I'm new to using `Foreign Keys` in `MySQL` scripts and I don't know why I'm getting these errors. If anyone could help me fix this, it would be appreciated. I've already tried all the answers that can be found by following this link [Bogus foreign key constraint fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334619/bogus-foreign-key-constraint-fail)

Comment: You may have to drop them in a different order to avoid violating foreign key constraints, remove the foreign keys first, or even disable the foreign keys.

Comment: @tadman I've just commented them out of the code and it's still happening

Comment: @Siguza It's not a duplication as I've tried all the answers given there and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Your Script is OK, but before `Dropping` Tables, try to remove the `Foreign Key References`

Comment: So it would be something along the lines of: `ALTER TABLE Track 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID);`?

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin or workbench? Or Consol!?

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench

Comment: Before the drop queries put this SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0

Comment: And before creating tables queries put this SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it to work